# FlutterFire update Array instead of replacing it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: FireStore structure]

so the `menus` field stores maps inside of an array/List. But when i want to add a map to `menus` it replaces all the existing ones with the new one, instead of adding a new one, here my code:

```dart
    Menu menuObj = Menu(
      name: menuName, categories: [
      Categories(
        name: categoryName,
      ),
    ]);

FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('menus/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}')
        .set({
      'menus': [
        menuObj.toJson(),
      ]
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Comment: have you tried changing your `set` method to `update` on firestore instance I guess that should work

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma nope that didn't work as well but I found out and wrote an answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69501959/14924556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use this code instead:

```dart
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc('menus/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}')
        .set({
      'menus': FieldValue.arrayUnion([menuObj.toJson()])
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Important part is this: `FieldValue.arrayUnion([menuObj.toJson()])`.